# Go-idiomatic naming of slice types

Tags: go

When I need methods on slices I have to declare a new type. But what should I name it?

`type SliceSomething []Something` or `type SomethingSlice []Something`?

Since it's read as "slice of something" the first one seems better, but autocomplete would probably prefer the second one.

Comment: Just make it plural like in the std lib: [Strings](http://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Strings), [Ints](http://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Ints)

Comment: @JimB would you mind writing that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [CodeReview wiki page](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments)

> Variable names in Go should be short rather than long.
>   This is especially true for local variables with limited scope.
>   Prefer `c` to `lineCount`. Prefer `i` to `sliceIndex`.
>
> The basic rule: the further from its declaration that a name is used, the more descriptive the name must be.

That is why you won't find "`Slice`" often in the go sources, except in:

```
encoding/gob/encoder_test.go:335:  type recursiveSlice []recursiveSlice
encoding/json/encode_test.go:107:  type renamedByteSlice []byte
encoding/json/encode_test.go:108:  type renamedRenamedByteSlice []renamedByte
regexp/onepass.go:283:             type runeSlice []rune
sort/sort.go:233:                  type IntSlice []int
sort/sort.go:243:                  type Float64Slice []float64
sort/sort.go:258:                  type StringSlice []string
unicode/maketables.go:1118:        type runeSlice []rune
```

So if you *have* to put '`Slice`' in the name, it would be **`type SomethingSlice []Something`** rather than `type SliceSomething []Something`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Go source code](http://github.com/golang/go) for generally recognized idioms.

Comment: This is basically a "link only" answer. Could you *also* find the information @Filip is looking for and post it here? It's much more useful for people coming asking the same question in the future.