# How to use all the processor cores in the for loop?

Tags: go, multicore

I have a standard for loop. I have an 8 core processor, 16 threads. When I run this loop, I see that I only have 1 thread utilized for 100%. 
I want one loop from my example to be handled by all CPU cores, is this possible? 
I saw the goroutine, but there is usually, depending on the context, i.e., parallel independent tasks. Can someone fix my code so that it uses all CPU cores?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(runtime.NumCPU())
    fmt.Println("hi man!");
    timestart := time.Now();

    for i := int64(0); i < 9007199915; i++ {
        if (testMy(i) == true) {
            fmt.Println("was returned true")
        }
    }

    timeend := time.Now();

    fmt.Print(timeend.Sub(timestart));
}



func testMy(someInteger int64) (bool) {
    if (someInteger == 5) {
        return true;
    } else if (someInteger == 900199) {
        return true;
    } else if (someInteger == 9001999) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

update: Can anyone suggest a programming language where it is exactly in this case can make it? That is, take my FOR LOOP Cycle and at a low level parallelize it.

Comment: You need to first split up the work into parallelize-able pieces, which depends on what your real problem is.

Comment: I understand that. Is it possible without splitting? So, that the operating system does it for me.

Comment: There's no automatic way to do this. Go requires you to be very explicit which has it's ups and downs. You should look into Go's channels and how to use them with goroutines.

Comment: You can't use multiple cores if you don't have something to run concurrently on multiple cores. There are certain classes of problems that some languages may be able to automatically parallelize, a simple linear counter is not one of them

Comment: Okay thanks, that is really my task can't be done.

Comment: I needed it for the benchmark.

Comment: (granted you could make this a lot less efficient by doing the comparisons in goroutines, but that didn't seem like a logical solution)

Comment: "Can anyone suggest a programming language" no. Requests for recommendations are specifically off-topic for SO.

Comment: @GenRIH sorry but your comments don't make any sense.  Of course, you can write a Go program to use as many cores as you like to do your task.  It's just that the task in question would be pointless to parallelize

Comment: @Vorsprung, I need a Sequential execution of the entire loop using all cores, that is always 5 should be processed before 6. Go was positioned as a multiprocessor language, it turned out that it is more of a marketing slogan. So your comment doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: @GenRiH: no, the request doesn't make sense, because that's not how multiprocessor systems work. If you require that each check be processed sequentially, that by definition means you cannot do anything in parallel across multiple processors.

Comment: @JimB, are you sure? In my opinion, for example, mysql at low level is multiprocessor and there you will have serial executions on many cores at once. Yes I know mysql is not a programming language. If the language allows multiprocessing in the form of manual control, it is better to call it as a language in which you can start processes on other cores with your Hands, it will be more honest.

Comment: @Vorsprung Please move to chat if you would like to lead a conversation. Comments are only for asking for clarifications.

Answer (score 3):

It is simple in **Go**, just divide your task between CPU cores using goroutines.
Let me give you an example (See this `for k := 0; k < nCPU; k++ {...}` loop):
Imagine you need to know the biggest 64-bit prime number using all CPU cores (Similar to your question here is a for loop, which I divided between CPU cores: `for i := start; i <= end && atomic.LoadInt32(&quit) == 0; i += 2 {...}`):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
)

func main() {
    // find max uint64 prime
    n := uint64(math.MaxUint64)
    for ; !isOddPrime(n); n -= 2 {
    }
    fmt.Println(n) // 18446744073709551557
}

var nCPU = runtime.NumCPU()

func isOddPrime(n uint64) bool {
    q := uint64(math.Sqrt(float64(n)))
    step := q / uint64(nCPU)
    if step&1 == 1 {
        step++ // make it even
    }
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(nCPU)
    var quit int32
    start := uint64(3)
    for k := 0; k < nCPU; k++ {
        end := start + step
        if end > q {
            end = q
        }
        go func(start, end uint64) {
            defer wg.Done()
            for i := start; i <= end && atomic.LoadInt32(&quit) == 0; i += 2 {
                if n%i == 0 {
                    atomic.StoreInt32(&quit, 1)
                    return
                }
            }
        }(start, end)
        start = end + 2
    }
    wg.Wait()
    return quit == 0
}
```

Output with 8 cores:

```
18446744073709551557
real    0m5.551s
user    0m39.059s
sys     0m0.040s
```

Output with 1 core:

```
18446744073709551557
real    0m23.704s
user    0m23.611s
sys     0m0.024s
```

---

The original code (without the synchronization and scheduling overhead):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func isOddPrime(n uint64) bool {
    q := uint64(math.Sqrt(float64(n)))
    for i := uint64(3); i <= q; i += 2 {
        if n%i == 0 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func main() { // find max uint64 prime
    n := uint64(math.MaxUint64)
    for ; !isOddPrime(n); n -= 2 {
    }
    fmt.Println(n) // 18446744073709551557
}
```

Output for `go version go1.13.4 linux/amd64` with `go build -o $TMPDIR/main && time $TMPDIR/main`:

```
18446744073709551557

real    0m24.002s
user    0m24.002s
sys     0m0.012s
```

Comment: Yup, I misread the original code (though the OP specifically said they didn't want to divide up the work and keep a single for loop, but this would be a way to do it). I bet we can do even better here :)

Comment: @JimB Of course, Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I've already divided my number by 4 and run the loop through 4 gorutins, but it's 1) not what I need, the code numbers don't count sequentially, but chaotically 2) it's a creepy overhead and a place for possible bugs. By the way, the code becomes poorly readable if you use variables as letters (q,n), I thought it was in php left.

Comment: @A.R Ah, I see where my concern would lie with this particular example, this only works well because the prime your looking for is only 58 less than MaxUint64, so there are actually relatively few goroutines dispatched. We'd need a different chunking algorithm, and/or maybe a worker-pool pattern for something that required a deeper search. Still demonstrates that you need to somehow chunk the problem though.

Comment: @GenRiH There are other methods for concurrency in Go e.g. using channels [see this example](https://play.golang.org/p/tN6RDz87w-M), and sometimes no concurrency is the way to go, see [this code](https://play.golang.org/p/5C0iYLOg1Sq) it just takes 30 seconds to find all 32-bit primes. The point is it is problem-dependent.

Comment: @GenRiH: Variable names in Go should be short rather than long. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27989517/8208215) and [this](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments). For your previous comment "you use variables as letters (q,n), I thought it was in php left.". I hope this helps.